# How to effectively demonstrate sharepoint skills?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, sharepoint-hosted-app

If I was to signup with office 365 and their hosted sharepoint server, would I be able to create a sample project that could demonstrate to a potential employer that I have the skills?

i.e. I currently do contract work `.net/mvc/etc`, but I want to get into sharepoint but remain as a contractor.  Realizing this, I need some sort of an example project to show that I can do this type of work

Any suggestions?  Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can.

You have to create a app using your development skills and deploy the App to store and from their you can give the demo.

[SharePoint 2013 development overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164084.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[SharePoint 2013 Online App Development](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/690015/SharePoint-Online-App-Development-Part)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Waqas mentioned you can create an APP and add it to a SharePoint store and then showcase it to your perspective clients. But that's just a small portion of what SharePoint can do. I used to do heavy C# SharePoint since 2007 but last two years its mostly JS and client side code. Its a big shift, and most work will be on a client side these days in office 365.

Thus i would suggest:

1. Learn how to brand a sharepoint site, nothing turns off a client than OOB SP Site
2. Create custom webpart/s that showcase your client side (JS) skills.
3. Learn about provisioning and list creations. Content Types and possibly Document Sets.
4. If you have a custom iis/azure server, create your own timer job/ or rest service and consume it from SharePoint.

Good luck.